# Pyinstaller- Failed to execute script script.py

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

after running the exe file, an error occurs in the windows console:

```
Traceback (most recent coll last):
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init.py", line 2261, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:...

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

as I understand it, the error indicates the 10th line of code in the script

line 10 in script.py:

```
root = Tk()
```

this is code:
https://github.com/nurikb/tkinter/blob/main/tk_json.py

here is the pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller.exe script.py -w --icon=favicon.ico
```